# How did git dots are displayed over the website

Tags: html, web, styles, division

Navigating to website https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/

Pasting the screenshot , its a public domain website so I dont think there would be content copyright issues

[image: Git Dotted Lines website Screenshot]

I like the dotted pattern on the webpage . I first thought its an image but when I did Inspect element nowhere I was able to see the image or any css style that was applied to display those dots. How that dotted pattern is acheived ?

Comment: you're not able to see it in inspect element as it is smartly put inside `:before` element state. check `post__header` within their CSS and you'll find the image and how they put it there.

Comment: and let us know how you are planning to use the approach on your web page

Comment: [:before/::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/8710338/himanshu-jain - Actually I am thinking to make own blog to share coding related stuff I would like to use this approach Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see it inspect like this under `header` tag pseudo-class [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) (CSS2 syntax)

[image: Github]

Answer (score 2):

You're not able to see it in inspect element as it is smartly put inside [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) element state.

Check `.post__header:before` within their CSS and you'll find the image and how they put it there.

```css
.post__header:before{
    background:url(/wp-content/themes/github-blog/dist/css/../../assets/images/dot-left-corner.png) no-repeat;
    content:none;
    height:300px;
    left:0;
    pointer-events:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    transform:translate(-125px,-152px);
    width:318px
}
```

There are more elements in the same page using this method instead of any direct approach.

Comment: idk if it's better than ours but atleast he and I mentioned `:before` state in one go. I like this brawl though.